# What different between im2bw(gray_image, level); & gray_image < 175;?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

HI all I am new to Matlab Image Processing toolbox, I really cannot decide to use between

```
im2bw(gray_image, level); 
gray_image < 0.5; ?
```

for im2bw(gray_image, **level**); level we can use the the value **0.5** or other value too?

Could anyone please explain me, If I want to Threshold a gray image, which one is better if I want to adjust the threshold level myself ?

If it is the same please kindly tell me thank...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `im2bw` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) says:

> Specify `level` in the range [0,1]. This range is relative to the signal levels possible for the image's class. Therefore, a level value of 0.5 is midway between black and white, regardless of class

This makes it slightly more flexible/convenient than `image < level`; depending on how you obtained the image, the values might be in the range 0-255, in which case your alternative would not give the desired result. Otherwise they are equivalent.